# sort list by number of whitespaces

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a textfile that looks like this:

```
prefix-56678     4677878     233454
3445567     56566767
4554578    prefix-787856
345456    546    7867856   445456
```

I want to re-order the lines by number of "\t" in line.
What I did was:

```
list_of_lines=text.splitlines()
list_of_lines.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
```

Yet the prefix is quite long and sometimes I get an error. I suppose I should use a generator, but can't figure out the syntax, any help?

Comment: You are sorting by the *line length*, not by number of tabs. What error do you get? The code you posted won't throw an exception.

Comment: `key=lambda x: x.count('\t')`

Comment: How long the prefix is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort your lines by tab count, count tabs:

```
list_of_lines.sort(key=lambda l: l.count('\t'), reverse=True)
```

`len()` gives you the total length of the line instead.

Comment: thanks!! I suppose it's time for me to study lambda functions!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_lines=text.splitlines()
list_of_lines.sort(key=lambda(x):len(x.split("\t"))-1, reverse=True)
```

Comment: While I prefer Martijn's `str.count` answer (PS: is that guy a robot?), yours would also work. However, you don't need to subtract 1 from every value. As long as the relative output of the key function stays the same, the absolute values don't count for anything.

Answer (score -2):

Here:

    `list_of_lines=text.splitlines()
    for elmntindx in range(len(list_of_lines)):
        list_of_lines[elmntindx].split("\t")
    list_of_lines.sort(key=len, reverse=True)`

Edit: Forgot to assign in line 3. Here is the fix with an additional part that combines your strings back:

    `list_of_lines=text.splitlines()
    for elmntindx in range(len(list_of_lines)):
        list_of_lines[elmntindx]=list_of_lines[elmntindx].split("\t")
    list_of_lines.sort(key=len, reverse=True) 
    for a in range(len(list_of_lines)):
        list_of_lines[a]="\t".join(list_of_lines[a])`

Comment: That won't work at all. `.split()` doesn't (and can't!) mutate strings. It returns a list instead. Your code is splitting each string and then discarding the output.

Comment: I just forgot assigning what was splitted :/. You can always use "\t".join() to combine your string back though.